# firebase dashboard doesn't show admob revenue

Tags: firebase, admob, firebase-console

I know stackoverflow is not helpdesk for google products, but google helpdesk itself is not helpful so maybe someone else here shared the same problem and can help me to solve.

I've an app published on google play for the past 3 months

all the app stuff is properly connected, firebase->admob->google play console->adsense... everything was done during the previous 3 months

but last week, without any reason, without any update in the app or any settings change in these tools, firebase dashboard stopped showing the admob revenue

[image]

as you can see at this graph, it considers from 16th to 22th nov my app just made 0.17 revenue on admob

but on admob itself i've

[image]

the blue bars are admob revenue while the green is in-app purchases, so it keeps registering, the admob graph doesn't show the sum of admob revenue but doesn't need to be a genius to see its something around 70.00 way more than 0.17

I've checked in firebase->events tab and all events like ad_click ad_reward ad_impression are still being counted

does anyone have any idea about what might be?
AGAIN: THIS WORKED FINE FOR ABOUT 3 MONTHS STOPPED WORKING LAST WEEK FOR A REASON I DONT KNOW

i asked for support on firebase but the guy just pointed me a couple of guides which i had already followed and didn't solve my problem.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7378163?hl=en
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6387949

Comment: +50 bounty and nobody have even a guess? why god why? google and its services killing me

Comment: Did you get it sorted?

Comment: Same issue here, all firebase data stopped flowing to firebase :/ still showing up in admob. All I changed so far is added the AdActivity to the manifest of my app to tweak the theme (which was causing a crash on 8.0)

Comment: @RafaelLima did you find a solution?

Comment: No, and since i'm jumping out of google 'in_app_purchase' system, i dont even care anymore, i will find my way to track revenue... I've an open ticket on both firebase and admob suport for over 20 days and nobody found solution

Comment: Yeah, I think I saw your ticket. This is crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 22 days I finally got google to admit what i knew since the begining:

IT'S A BUG ON FIREBASE

[image]

the link he sent is: https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Again his is incoherent, if it is an error between admob->firebase data exchange what kind of sdk release will fix it? and why should i have an eye on it?
this interface is invisible an inacessible to all devs... as should be any fix on it

Anyway, if anyone else is having a similar problem that is the final answer from google

Comment: Came here to post that. I wonder if they are gonna update the revenue. Since the events are accounted for if you look at the "events" section tables

Comment: Hey just reporting; I think they fixed the bug in firebase. Not sure if it's fixed on admob though still having a low revenue but firebase just started reporting revenue again.